# import, en entorno virtual, falla en script

Tags: python, virtualenv

Todo lo que sigue se ejecuta en entorno virtual.
Tengo un script que realiza un import al módulo netifaces.
el paquete aparece en **pip list**
Cuando lo ejecuto en modo interactivo, realiza el import sin problemas, pero cuando
lo ejecuto como script, me falla.

Version simple del script:

```
import socket               # Import socket module
import netifaces

print("Hello")
```

Captura de mensajes en el terminal:

```
Package                           Version
--------------------------------- -------
backports.entry-points-selectable 1.1.1
distlib                           0.3.3
filelock                          3.3.2
ipaddress                         1.0.23
netaddr                           0.8.0
netifaces                         0.11.0
pip                               21.3.1
platformdirs                      2.4.0
pyasn1                            0.4.8
pysmb                             1.2.7
setuptools                        58.5.3
virtualenv                        20.10.0
wheel                             0.36.2

(venv) C:\Temp_C_10\Proyectos\PruebasSMB>py
Python 3.10.0 (tags/v3.10.0:b494f59, Oct  4 2021, 19:00:18) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import socket
>>> import netifaces
>>> print("hello")
hello
>>> quit()

(venv) C:\Temp_C_10\Proyectos\PruebasSMB>py test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Temp_C_10\Proyectos\PruebasSMB\test.py", line 10, in <module>
    import netifaces
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'netifaces'

(venv) C:\Temp_C_10\Proyectos\PruebasSMB>
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?
¿Qué omito?
¿Qué no acabo de comprender?

Edito y añado información, según recomendación:

Parece que he encontrado la causa, aunque no la acabo de comprender por completo. Si alguien me puede aportar más información se lo agradecería.

He añadido al programa, que me imprima sys.path. Lanzando el script como py test.py, sys.path no recoge el entorno virtual, cosa que si que hace cuando lo lanzo como python test.py.

Comment: Según el error, Python busca un modulo llamado netifaces y no lo está encontrando. Que es netifaces?

Comment: netifaces es un paquete para acceder a información de los interfaces de red.
**https://pypi.org/project/netifaces/**

En mi caso estoy intentado modificar el siguiente ejemplo:

**# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41625274/extracting-subnet-mask-from-my-computer-python**. Mi problema es por que cuando esta en modo interactivo si parece que lo encuentra, y cuando está en modo script no lo encuentra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un entorno virtual no es más que una carpeta que contiene un intérprete de python, un ejecutable `pip`, las bibliotecas básicas para que python funcione, y todas las bibliotecas adicionales que hayas instalado con el `pip` de ese entorno.

Una vez has creado el entorno (por ejemplo escribiendo `python -m venv prueba`) verás que aparece una carpeta con ese nombre (`prueba`) y si entras en ella verás toda una instalación Python, compuesta por carpetas como `bin`, `lib`, `include`, etc...

En particular es dentro de la carpeta `bin` (`prueba/bin` en el ejemplo) donde está el intérprete `python` y el ejecutable `pip` , entre otras cosas.

Normalmente el siguiente paso es "activar" el entorno virtual, pero esto en realidad es solo un paso opcional para que sea más cómodo manejarlo.

Aún sin activarlo se puede utilizar si siempre que ejecutes python te aseguras de estar ejecutando el que está en el entorno (es decir `prueba/bin/python`) y si siempre que quieras instalar nuevos paquetes te a seguras de usar el `pip` que está en ese entorno (es decir `prueba/bin/pip`).

Al ser lanzado, el ejecutable python averigua en qué ruta (carpeta) está guardado, y prepara `sys.path` adecuadamente. Por eso si ejecutas el python que está dentro del entorno virtual `sys.path` contendrá rutas a ese entorno, pero si ejecutas el `python` que está afuera (el python de sistema), no las contendrá.

Lo único que hace el script `activate` es modificar tu variable de entorno `PATH` para añadirle por delante la ruta `prueba/bin` y de ese modo puedes escribir `python` a secas y se ejecutará el que hay en `prueba/bin` sin necesidad de especificar la ruta completa hacia él.

Sospecho que en tu caso usar `py` causa que se ejecute el python "de sistema" en lugar de el python del entorno virtual. Esto se debería a que dentro del entorno virtual no existe un comando `prueba/bin/py`, por lo que saltará al siguiente elemento del PATH hasta encontrarlo.

Si tienes dudas acerca de qué python exactamente es el que se va a ejecutar poniendo `python` "a secas" (o poniendo `py` o `pip` o cualquier otro comando), puedes usar el comando `which python` en linux (en windows creo que sería `where python`) que te imprime la ruta hasta el ejecutable que será usado.